# Combining arrays in javascript into an array of hashes where one array is all the keys the rest are values

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a couple of arrays that look like the following:

`var foo = ['id', 'first', 'last'];`
`var student1 = ['1', 'sam', 'smith'];`
`var student2 = ['2', 'jon', 'murphy'];`

Is there an efficient tool, perhaps using a library like `underscore.js` or `vanilla` javascript that will allow you to turn those three arrays into an object that looks like the following:

`var finalObj = [
   {'id' => 1, 'first' => 'sam', 'last' => 'smith'},
   {'id' => 2, 'first' => 'jon', 'last' => 'murphy'}
 ];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution in plain Javascript

```js
var foo = ['id', 'first', 'last'],
    student1 = ['1', 'sam', 'smith'],
    student2 = ['2', 'jon', 'murphy'],
    result = [student1, student2].map(function (a) {
        var o = {};
        foo.forEach(function (k, i) {
            o[k] = a[i];
        });
        return o;
    });

console.log(result);
```

ES6 with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var keys = ['id', 'first', 'last'],
    st1 = ['1', 'sam', 'smith'],
    st2 = ['2', 'jon', 'murphy'],
    result = [st1, st2].map(a => keys.reduce((o, k, i) => (o[k] = a[i], o), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the order of the arrays always matters (it will always be ID, First, Last) - you could do something like:

```
var people = [student1, student2]; //create 2d array
var finalObj = people.reduce(function(final, person) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[foo[0]] = person[0]
    obj[foo[1]] = person[1]
    obj[foo[2]] = person[2]
    final.push(obj);
    return final;
}, []);

//[Objectfirst: "sam"id: "1"last: "smith"__proto__: Object, Objectfirst: "jon"id: "2"last: "murphy"__proto__: Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

Underscore can help, for example:

```
_.map( [student1, student2], function(arr) {
     return _.object(foo, arr);
})
```